# Feed formats other than pbf to Osmosis

Tags: java, openstreetmap, osmosis, osm.pbf

I've written code in Java using the [Osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) framework and specifically OsmosisReader for Java, for OSM processing.

As far as I understand, OsmosisReader can only work with `*.pbf` files, which means I need to convert `.osm` files before using them (which I'm currently doing with [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert)).

Is there a way to use other OSM formats with OsmosisReader? And if not, is there a way to convert the file format through the code (preferably with Osmosis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `osmosis-xml` package offers the [`XmlReader`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.openstreetmap.osmosis/osmosis-xml/latest/org/openstreetmap/osmosis/xml/v0_6/XmlReader.html) class. It can be used to read OSM data in XML-based formats (.osm, .osm.bz2 and .osm.gz).

Both `OsmosisReader` and `XmlReader` implement the [`RunnableSource`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.openstreetmap.osmosis/osmosis-core/latest/org/openstreetmap/osmosis/core/task/v0_6/RunnableSource.html) interface, so you can go through that interface if you want your code to support multiple input formats.